# How to use hidesBarsOnSwipe to hide the NavigationBar when UITableView is embedded into a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Apple added this hidesBarsOnSwipe helper that is really nice to trigger a NavigationBar hide/show action when we scroll up and down in a list of items.

I have a UIPageViewController with many tableViews inside.
I would like to show/hide the navigation bar in exactly the same way hidesBarsOnSwipe does when I scroll up/down in my UITableView(s)

Unfortunately, When I set the following code in a UITableView class:

```
  rootNavViewCtrl?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
  rootNavViewCtrl?.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didHideOnSwipe))

  func didHideOnSwipe() {
    log.debug("==== hide on swipe ====")
  }
```

It doesn't trigger the function.
It actually triggers the function only when I start an horizontal scroll swipe (I guess UIPageViewController triggers the gesture recognizer) and then end it by a motion in diagonal up or down...

Anybody have a clean solution for this?

Comment: Did you solve it? We are stuck on this for days now..

Comment: I didn't finally hide it on scroll at that time and I don't know if the proposed solution is 100% working fine but from what I read it should be working well. I'm just not sure that the animation will be smooth or not when trying to scroll up and down. Also, when switching to another horizontal page, will it not bug? If you can test his proposed code and paste a swift solution, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this code into Swift. What I provided is in Obj-C syntax.

Inside your view controller which contains the tableView, override few UIScrollView delegates:

```
BOOL canHideOrShowNavBar;
NSInteger lastContentOffset;

 #pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y && canHideOrShowNavBar){
        if(self.parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden){
            [self.parentViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }
    }else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y && canHideOrShowNavBar){
        if(!self.parentViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden){
            [self.parentViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        }
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    canHideOrShowNavBar = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                 withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
          targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    canHideOrShowNavBar = NO;
}

- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([self.parentViewController.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
        [self.parentViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

If you have multiple view controllers under the UIPageViewController which also have UITableView, you can put these codes in your base UIViewController subclass to prevent redundancy.

---

At the same time, I wish someone can enlighten me too on why ***hidesBarsOnSwipe*** is not working when UITableView is inside the childViewController in UIPageViewController.

```
UINavigationController //Initiate
  | 
UIPageViewController 
  |                   |                   |
UIViewControllerA   UIViewControllerB   UIViewControllerC
  |             ↘
UITableView  // <self.navigationController.canHideOrShowNavBar = YES; is not working when scrolling UITableView>
```